# How to add a floating toolbar to QFrame in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4, qmainwindow

I have made a stand alone application inheriting from base class `QtGui.QFrame`, and now I want to add a floating toolbar to it as can be done in a `QMainWindow`. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it with QFrame. According to docs you can have toolbar in allowed areas.
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtoolbar.html#allowedAreas-prop

But I'm not sure.

Comment: well, i have added already ,

toolbar = QtGui.QToolbar()
toolbar.setFloatable(True)
toolbar.setMovable(True)

and added the layout that contained the buttonsI want to place to this toolbar.

now I got the toolbar and layout containg the toolbar and the buttons that i wanted to be in the toolbar all showing up, but the toolbar I have added to the default main VBoxLayout() isnt floating :-(

Comment: This is wrong use of toolbar. You add actions or specific widgets to toolbar, not layout for sure. And setMovable makes sense only if toolbar is in QMainWindow. floatable means that toolbar itself is another window, not part of your QFrame.

Comment: alright then, can you please show me with an example how do I do it if I have to create a QToolbar with QFrame?

Comment: As I wrote before you most probably can't use QToolbar on QFrame. You can make your own custom widget that will act like toolbar, but I don't recommend it. First you have to know what toolbar really is. Look at [this screenshot](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Inkscape0.45_ru_toolbars_deattach_xfce4trt.png/800px-Inkscape0.45_ru_toolbars_deattach_xfce4trt.png), toolbars are these bars on top, right and bottom. Right now they are floating, but you can dock them to main window. Toolbars has specific area allowed only in window, hence you can't add one to QFrame.

Comment: i was reading about it , so I guess i have to use QMainWindow that makes more sense to add toolbar does that applies to QDockWidget as well that I can only add it to QMainWindow ?

Comment: yes, dock widget can be added to QMainWindow only as well, and for this one I'm sure :)

Comment: It is possible to use a QToolBar without a QMainWindow, but with some limitations (from docs): When a QToolBar is not a child of a QMainWindow, it loses the ability to populate the extension pop up with widgets added to the toolbar using addWidget(). Please use widget actions created by inheriting QWidgetAction and implementing QWidgetAction.createWidget() instead.